# Using postman to upload an image to nodejs backend service

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, postman

I'm new in nodejs, and during the test of my post method that upload image from the computer I get in postman this message that shows that my upload method doesn't exist [image]

my server.js code is

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();

//moddleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(multer.json(''));

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 5000;   

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null,"/images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null,file.fieldname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
    }).array('image',3);
//route
app.post('/', (req, res) => {});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res , err => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('somthing went wrong');
        }
        return.res.send('file uploaded successfully');
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log('Server running on PORT ${PORT}')
});
```

and this is my server response

```
 [nodemon] 2.0.7                                                    
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`                       
    [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*                                    
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json                         
    [nodemon] starting `node server.js`                                
    Server running on PORT ${PORT}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

your code has some error inside the upload route return.res.send which is causing the issue. make changes as follow.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 5000;   

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: Storage }).array('image', 12)

//route
app.post('/', (req, res) => {});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res , err => {
        if (err) {
            res.send('somthing went wrong');
        }
        res.send('file uploaded successfully');
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server running on PORT ${PORT}')
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but still the same issue, I have a problem in the declaration of the method but where exactly that what I don't know.
is there any other way to test a method?

Answer (score 1):

I finally made  it here is the code

```
// const bodyParser= require('body-parser');

const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 5000;   

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, file.orignalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({
 storage: Storage 
}).array('image', 3);
//route
app.post('/', (req, res) => {});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    upload(req, res , err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send('somthing went wrong');
        }
        return res.send('file uploaded successfully');
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server running on PORT ${PORT}')
});
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: btw I add a new folder in the project called "images"